# Hollow a design to 3D Print

Tags: 3d-printing

Does anyone know how to make an object hollow in order to cut cost for 3D prints? I want to create and upload to shapeways.com to make metal jewelry. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the solidify modifier?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html?highlight=solidify

Comment: Can you update your question with a picture of your model. Different models require different approaches due to complexity.

Comment: @Psyonic I even tried hollowing the standard Blender cube using Solidify but it still uploads to shapewayys as solid. My apologies, I'm new to forums and I don't see how to upload a picture.

Comment: I've not used Shapeways but the object probably needs a hole in it to be considered "hollow" If it just a shell then resin printing will not be able to drain the resin out so they might truncate any internal structures.
You can add pictures to your post with the bar above where you write the text, the little symbol that looks like a mountain with a sun

Comment: It depends on the software you are using to convert your mesh to stl, usually if your mesh is manifold you will be able to tweak the settings to make it hollow